# Criar array apartir de form dinamica em PHP

Tags: php, html

Boa noite galera. Como consigo obter as informações de uma form com inputs dinâmicas em array?
As inputs dinâmicas é quando o usuário clica em um botão solicitando mais inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá para fazer, vou fazer com jQuery, adicione jQuery às suas tags sff. Você pode fazer assim como exemplifico em baixo:

HTML:
   Adicionar nome/email dos amigos:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="campos">
        Nome:<br>
        <input name="nomes[]">
        Email:<br>
        <input name="emails[]">
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<button class="add_friend">Adicionar amigo</button>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.add_friend').on('click', function(){
    var campos = $('.campos').eq(0).clone(); // copiar só um destes elementos, escolhi copiar o primeiro que é o unico que tenho a certeza que vai sempre existir
    campos.find('input').val(''); // por o valor dos inputs dos novos campos (nome/email) vazios para o caso de termos preenchido já nos primeiros inputs ($('.campos').eq(0))
    $('input[type="submit"]').before(campos);
});
```

Depois de submeter o formulário.

Servidor (PHP) EX:

```
print_r($_POST['names']); // array('miguel', 'patricia', 'claudia');
print_r($_POST['emails']); // array('miguel@miguel.com', 'patricia@patricia.com', 'claudia@claudia.com');
//$
```

Aqui atenção que devemos fazer validações para cada um dos nomes/emails,  nem que seja só se estão vazios e/ou passar por algum tipo de sanitização

Exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4kz3e81/13/)